# How to cache value returned by method, which is dependent on attributes of other classes?

Tags: python, oop

## Simplified code (no caching)

First a piece of simplified code, which I'll use to explain the problem.

```
def integrate(self, function, range):
    # this is just a naive integration function to show that
    # function needs to be called many times
    sum = 0
    for x in range(range):
        sum += function(x) * 1
    return sum

class Engine:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity

class Chasis:
    def __init__(self, weigth):
        self.weight = weight

class Car:
    def __init__(self, engine, chassis):
        self.engine = engine
        self.chassis = chassis
    def average_acceleration(self):
        # !!! this calculations are actually very time consuming
        return self.engine.capacity / self.chassis.weight
    def velocity(self, time):
        # here calculations are very simple
        return time * self.average_acceleration()
    def distance(self, time):
        2 + 2 # some calcs
        integrate(velocity, 2000)
        2 + 2 # some calcs

engine = Engine(1.6)
chassis = Chassis(500)
car = Car(engine, chassis)
car.distance(2000)
chassis.weight = 600
car.distance(2000)
```

## Problem

`Car` is the main class. It has an `Engine` and a `Chassis`.

`average_acceleration()` uses attributes from Engine and Chassis and performs very time consuming calculations.

`velocity()`, on the other hand, perfoms very simple calculations, but uses a value calculated by `average_acceleration()`

`distance()` passes `velocity` function to `integrate()`

Now, `integrate()` calls many times `velocity()`, which calls each time **`average_acceleration()`**. Considering that the value returned by `average_acceleration()` depends only on Engine and Chassis, it'd be desirable to cache the value returned by `average_acceleration()`.

## My ideas

### First attempt (not working)

Fist I though about using a [memoize decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) in the following manner:

```
    @memoize
    def average_acceleration(self, engine=self.engine, chassis=self.chassis):
        # !!! this calculations are actually very time consuming
        return engine.capacity / chassis.weight
```

But it won't work as I want, because Engine and Chassis are mutable. Thus, if do:

```
chassis.weight = new_value
```

average_acceleration() will return wrong (previously cached) value on the next call.

### Second attempt

Finally I modified the code as follows:

```
    def velocity(self, time, acceleration=None):
        if acceleration is None:
            acceleration = self.average_acceleration()
        # here calculations are very simple
        return time * acceleration 
    def distance(self, time):
        acceleration = self.average_acceleration()
        def velocity_withcache(time):
            return self.velocity(time, acceleration)
        2 + 2 # some calcs
        integrate(velocity_withcache, 2000)
        2 + 2 # some calcs
```

I added the parameter `acceleration` to `velocity()` method. Having that option added, I calculate `acceleration` only once in `distance()` method, where I know that chassis and engine objects are not changed and I pass this value to velocity.

## Bottom line

The code I wrote does what I need it to do, but I'm curious if you can come up with someting better/cleaner?

Comment: +1 Probably the best written homework question I've seen. (I assume this is homework)

Comment: Thanks. Actually this is not a homework, but I'm not a professional programmer, so I guess it may look like one ;-)

Comment: If the acceleration is constant (as it appears to be in the `distance` method), then you should be able to compute the distance with calculus, no computational integration necessary. `distance = 1/2 * acceleration * time**2`.

Comment: @unutbu, Obviously this is, as I did point out, simplified code. My real calculations are way more complex, I just tried to boil down here what my problem with caching is about.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is one that you've already identified: you're trying to `memoize` a function that accepts mutable arguments. This problem is very closely related to the reason python `dict`s don't accept mutable built-ins as keys.

It's also a problem that's very simple to fix. Write a function that only accepts immutable arguments, `memoize` that, and then create a wrapper function that extracts the immutable values from the mutable objects. So...

```
class Car(object):
    [ ... ]

    @memoize
    def _calculate_aa(self, capacity, weight):
        return capacity / weight

    def average_acceleration(self):
        return self._calculate_aa(self.engine.capacity, self.chassis.weight)
```

Your other option would be to use [property setters](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) to update the value of `average_acceleration` whenever relevant values of `Engine` and `Chassis` are changed. But I think that might actually be more cumbersome than the above. Note that for this to work, you have to use new-style classes (i.e. classes that inherit from `object` -- which you should really be doing anyway).

```
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._weight = None
        self.updated = False

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self._weight

    @weight.setter
    def weight(self, value):
        self._weight = value
        self.updated = True
```

Then in `Car.average_acceleration()` check whether `engine.updated`, recalculate aa if so, and set `engine.updated` to False. Pretty clunky, seems to me.

Comment: This is basically a fix for my first approach. I have already considered this solution and the problem I see, is that, what if `self.engine.capacity` and `self.chassis.weight` are mutable as well? Than I would have to go kind of "one layer deeper", right? This is potentially cumbersome. But maybe this is the only solution if I want to use memoization, because a cache key containig all variables must be created. On the other hand, maybe there is some other smart solution out there.

Comment: Honestly, the other solution to this problem that I can see is more cumbersome; see above.

Comment: Also, don't you already have to go "one layer deeper" to do your calculations? Surely your calculations are being done on immutable objects. So just `memoize` at whatever the lowest level is.

Comment: That is what @Zirak proposed in his answer and I agree this is less good. Yet, out of these two choices and my solution, I choose mine. But I guess yours would be the only solution in the case of more random access to `average_acceleration()`.

Comment: @senderle you wrote:"python dicts don't accept mutable objects as keys". While one cannot have builtin mutable (like list) as key there is nothing preventing from making an instance of a custom class as key (whose values can be modified), though this is a bad practice.So I think your statement is not necessarily correct.

Comment: Not really, because I pass some mutable attribute of chassis to the method of engine.

Comment: Honestly, the more I think about it, the more I feel that my solution is best, because it achieves greater separation of concerns. You shouldn't have a function that does complex calculations _and_ navigates a complex object hierarchy at the same time. Navigate the object hierarchy in a separate function and pass immutable objects to another function for calculation.

Answer (score 0):

There are various decorator implementations available on PyPI dealing with caching return value and taking the function parameters into account.

Check for *gocept.cache* or *plone.memoize* on PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just assign the long calculation as a property, and calculate it on initialization? If you need to calculate it again (e.g. you change the engine) then and only then would you need to call it again.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, engine, chassis):
        self.engine = engine
        self.chassis = chassis
        self.avg_accel = self.average_acceleration()
    def average_acceleration(self):
        # !!! this calculations are actually very time consuming
        return self.engine.capacity / self.chassis.weight
    def velocity(self, time):
        # here calculations are very simple
        return time * self.avg_accel
    def distance(self, time):
        2 + 2 # some calcs
        integrate(velocity, 2000)
        2 + 2 # some calcs
    def change_engine(self, engine):
        self.engine = engine
        self.avg_accel = self.average_acceleration()
```

Comment: What in case engine would be modified not through Car interface (outside the class)? Engine would have to be deepcopy'ed to make it work. But even then no changes could be made to engine inside car class, only new instance (or deep copy) could be created. Moreover, setter for each component, i.e. engine, chassis, etc., would be needed. This seems to be more messy than my solution.

Comment: Why? You still have the same reference to engine, and as said, if you want to make any changes to the engine, re-run the operation.

Comment: I mean, if I do somethink like this: `engine.capacity = 800`, the cached value of `average_acceleration` will not be reset.

Comment: How is that different than your solution?